# ReactJS - Root DOM node dynamically added

Tags: jquery, reactjs

I have a tabbed interface controlled by jquery in a legacy application.

I am migrating new parts to ReactJS.

One of the tabs holds the React root DOM node where I want my component to appear. The DOM node along with all the content in the tab will be loaded via jquery AJAX with the html() function as and when the tab is activated. In such a scenario, React fails to find the DOM node and fails with an error.

If I load the React script dynamically using AJAX on tab activation, it keeps adding a duplicate root component each time I load the script.

If I load the script only the first time when the tab is activated, it fails to add the component to DOM altogether on the second tab activation onwards.

How can I work with a dynamically inserted root DOM node in React (v16.2)?

Please help!

Comment: need to see some code. Are tab clicks reloading entire page? need to see the onload starter code as well.

Comment: @Subin, the tab content is loaded every time the tab is clicked via AJAX. The root node gets removed in the process and added back when the relevant tab is clicked again. I have found the solution mentioned below. Call ReactDOM.render() by exposing it via a wrapper at the window level. Thanks.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I found the solution.

Just write this in your main component file to control the react component from an external source like jQuery:

```
function renderComponent() {
  ReactDOM.render(<YourApp />, document.getElementById('your-root-node'));
}

window.initReact = renderComponent;

function unmountComponent() {
  ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(document.getElementById('your-root-node'));
}

window.unmountReact = unmountComponent;
```

Then call it like this in your jQuery code when you know that the root node has been added to the DOM:

```
initReact();
```

Call this when you are about to remove the root node from DOM (recommended to clean up state/any event handlers):

```
unmountReact();
```

Inspired from: https://medium.com/@michaelbrazell/invoking-reactdom-render-from-outside-of-react-86c3a3350bd7

Thanks

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19146667)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I have updated my answer with code now.